# NestJS with Typeorm can't resolve dependencies

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm

**Problem**

NestJS with Typeorm dependancy error.

**Description**

When I insert @InjectRepository into my Session Repository class (session.repository.ts), the can't dependency errors occur. However, if I remove the @InjectRepository the error disappear and the application works fine.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjMsW.png)

File: session.repository.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Session } from './session.entity';

@Injectable()
export class SessionRepository {
  constructor(
    // When I try to inject repository the error occur.
    // When I remove the inject repository, no error occur.
    @InjectRepository(Session)
    private readonly session: Repository<Session>,
  ) {}

  async test() {
    return await this.session.find();
  }
}
```

File: session.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ISessionConfig } from 'src/common/config/config.interface';
import { ConfigService } from 'src/common/config/config.service';
import { createHashedToken, getExpiresTime } from '../auth.helper';
import { SessionRepository } from './session.repository';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {
  private bytes: number;
  private ttl: number;

  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly sessionRepository: SessionRepository,
  ) {
    const sessionConfig = this.configService.get<ISessionConfig>('session');
    this.bytes = sessionConfig.bytes;
    this.ttl = sessionConfig.ttl;
  }

  getConfig(): ISessionConfig {
    return { bytes: this.bytes, ttl: this.ttl };
  }

  async generateRefreshToken() {
    const refreshToken = await createHashedToken(this.bytes);
    const expires = getExpiresTime(this.ttl).toString();
    return { refreshToken, expires };
  }
}
```

File: session.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Session } from './session.entity';
import { SessionRepository } from './session.repository';
import { SessionService } from './session.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Session])],
  providers: [SessionService, SessionRepository],
  exports: [SessionService, SessionRepository],
})
export class SessionModule {}
```

File: auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthenticationModule } from './authentication/authentication.module';
import { JwtModule } from './jwt/jwt.module';
import { SessionModule } from './session/session.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthenticationModule, JwtModule, SessionModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

File: database.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { IDatabaseConfig } from '../config/config.interface';
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions => {
        const dbConfig = configService.get<IDatabaseConfig>('database');
        return {
          type: 'mysql',
          host: dbConfig.host,
          port: dbConfig.port,
          username: dbConfig.username,
          password: dbConfig.password,
          database: dbConfig.database,
          entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          autoLoadEntities: true,
          synchronize: true,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

File: app.module.ts

```
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from './common/config/config.module';
import { DatabaseModule } from './common/database/database.module';
import { HttpLoggerMiddleware } from './common/middlewares/http-logger.middleware';
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';
import { PostsModule } from './modules/posts/posts.module';
import { UsersModule } from './modules/users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule, ConfigModule, DatabaseModule, PostsModule, UsersModule],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(HttpLoggerMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

I tried to solve the issue but, at the end, I am not able to solve it.

Please help me find the issue. Thank you.

**Updated**
I found out the problem, it is the naming issue. I changed the class name from SessionRepository -> SessionsRepository.

Comment: `entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}']` is not right.

Comment: I followed https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database
May I know what should I include in entities?

Comment: `entities` is an empty array in docs. The exact value depends on your folders structure however it is something like this: `entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}']`. You can also try including class itself like `entites: [Session]`

Comment: I tried both of your solutions, also not working, but anyways thank you very much. My other entities is working (User, Post), only the session is not working when I do @InjectRepository on SessionRepository.

Comment: is `SessionRepository` supposed to be a [custom repository](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-repository) or what? if not, its name is not accurate (to me)

Comment: @tattzetey Why didn't you mention Session entity code then?

Comment: @omidh it was my bad so sorry for that...I never thought the problem will be the name.

Comment: @Micael Levi Yes, it is a custom repository.

Comment: then you just don't need to inject the repository like you did, just `extends` like the docs shows

Comment: Okay no problem. Thank you.